# nodejs mssql query in function

Tags: jquery, sql-server, node.js

I´m trying to get the result of my query which is running in my function.

But my result is `undefined`. What i´m doing wrong?

function:

```
function sqllis(sql_q) {
  sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    var request = new sql.Request();
    request.query(sql_q, function (err, recordset) {
      return recordset.recordsets;
    });
  });
}
```

My try to get the result:

```
var result = sqllis("select * from dbo.sys_user ");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sql.query` function uses a [callback](http://dreamerslab.com/blog/en/javascript-callbacks/) meaning it is [asynchronous](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript) code. You cannot resolve the result synchronously. I am not sure whether you are using the `sql` or `mssql` npm library, but I'd suggest looking if there is a native promise approach or to wrap your code into a promise oriented approach. If you're using the `mssql` library, when omitting the callback, it returns automatically a promise and you can use it like this.

```
function sqllis(sql_q) {
    sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        var request = new sql.Request();
        return request.query(sql_q);
    });
}
```

and use it asynchronously like this:

```
sqllis("select * from dbo.sys_user ")
.then(function(results){ console.log(results) })
.catch(function(err){ console.log(err) });
```

You can also pass a callback function.

```
function sqllis(sql_q, callback) {
    sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query(sql_q, callback);
    });
}
```

and use it like this

```
sqllis("select * from dbo.sys_user ", function(err, results){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(results); //results.recordsets
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a `callback` to return results from an `async` function.

```
   function sqllis(sql_q, callback) {
        sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            var request = new sql.Request();
            request.query(sql_q, function (err, recordset) {
                callback(err, recordset); // USING CALLBACK
            });
        });
    }

    var result = sqllis("select * from dbo.sys_user ", (err,res) => {
         console.log(res);
    })
```

Reference articles you could go through:

- https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function